# Makefile Issue - Can't understand where the issue is

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I'm having a problem compiling my makefile and I don't understand what it's telling me.
Can somebody explain me what the makefile is telling me please?
[image]

[image]

Comment: its not the makefile telling you something; it's the compiler.

Comment: Well... on line 13 of the file guesser.c you have a prototype or definition of the function remainder than does not match the one in the header files. man remainder says 'double
     remainder(double x, double y);'

Comment: okay my remainder is just a table (void) in my C program it's not supposed to return anything.

Comment: is it better to paste my guesser.c for you to have a look?

Comment: @YannBohbot Not necessary. Although you don't show the code, the problem is quite clear from the warning (you posted) given by the compiler.

Comment: Consider 'gcc -Wall -W -pedantic'. You get a lot more helpful suggestions that way.

Comment: it's what the teacher's requesting me. I'm editing to the picture i had before it worked but it gave me another problem.
basically the teacher has the main i just needed to build the guesser.c but do you think this new edit is a problem from his side this time?

Comment: You have edited the question radically, removing *everything* people had been addressing and giving us the new error. Don't do that. Ask a separate question for a separate problem.

Answer (score 1):

`make` is giving you a pretty informative message:

```
make: stat: /u/courses/89-110/data/Ex4_files/main.c: Permission denied
```

So, my first guess is that `make` is being denied access to the file.  My first guess is that the file does not have read permission, or else the "owner" of the file is a user other than the user ID under which `make` is running.

I suggest you change directory to `/u/courses/89-110/data/Ex4_files` and then run the command `ls -l` and look at the permissions and ownership of `main.c` and other source files.

Here's a tutorial on permissions in *NIX:  http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Permissions.html